# Using Azure B2C with userName as login, How to Verify Authentication Email Address PRIOR to Sending Code in Password Reset Policy

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We're trying to implement Azure B2C in our legacy .Net Framework web application, using userName instead of email address to log in (we migrated accounts from a legacy system).  Our Password Reset/Forgot My Password custom policy is giving us trouble.  We based it off the example found [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin).  It "works", but the user flow is terrible.  They enter their username and auth email, click the button to send the code, get code from email, verify, then upon successful verification, they are asked to click Continue button.  Upon clicking continue, only then does it actually check if the email address provided matches the strong auth email on file for that user.  If not, it throws an error.  We want to change it up so it checks the provided username and email address to see it it's the auth email tied to the username BEFORE sending the code.  We've tried changing the order of the custom policy around, looking for samples, etc, and have had no luck.  Is this even possible?
Feel like it should be pretty straight-forward.  We have a userjourney with step 1 calling the TechnicalProfile (LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress) below, then step 2 is to update the pw if verified.  There's some black-box magic going on here, because in most examples I've seen they use AadSspr-SendCode and AadSspr-VerifyCode to do the verification, but I don't have that anywhere in my policies from the sample so I don't know where to hook into that process.  Been struggling with this for a week, hoping for some guidance!

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertEmailAndstrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
</InputClaims>
<InputParameters>
  <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
</InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
  <DisplayName>Reset password using username</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordchange1.1</Item>
    <Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>  <!-- this error is displayed if PW's don't match after verification -->
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Your account has been locked. Contact your support person to unlock it, then try again.</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    ...
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
        
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertEmailAndstrongAuthenticationEmailAddressAreEqual" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromObjectID" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadCommon" />
</TechnicalProfile>
        
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadCommon">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailsFromOtherMailsAndSignInNamesInfo" />
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AddStrongAuthenticationEmailToEmails" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Yes.  Even though it's XML-based, it's still programming/development.  Is there another forum that this would make more sense in?  There are loads of B2C/XML Custom Policy questions on SO already...that's why I picked here.

Comment: Valid question - B2C is XML as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to take "AAD-UserReadUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" out of "LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingUserNameAndValidateStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" and make it part of the user journey before calling "LocalAccountDiscovery".

But ensure you have "signInName" set up as an output claim.

You will find "AadSspr-SendCode" [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol/policy/SSPR) but it doesn't sound like you need it.